# template specialization based on a type's existance

Tags: c++, templates

I want to implement some functionality if a certain type is defined. The problem is that if the type doesn't exist, the compiler rejects the code as invalid. Something like a template based ifdef. This would be used in a library which doesn't know what the other code includes, and I want to implement functionality automagically if some library is also included. Maybe it's the wrong approach, but I want to know if this can be done without ifdefs with default behavior.

```
template <typename=std::enable_if<type_exists<some_type>>::type>
void function() {
   // code using some_type
}
template <>
void function() {
   // code using other_type
}
```

This code would choose the first function if some_type exists, and the second function if some_type is undefined. The code assumes other_type exists.

Another use case would be something like this.

```
template <typename T, typename=std::enable_if<type_exists<boost::shared_ptr<T>>>::type>
using ptr = boost::shared_ptr<T>;
template <typename T>
using ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;
```

To prefer boost pointers IF the user of the library included boost, otherwise fall back to std::shared_ptr.

Comment: I don't understand how the type of `function` is supposed to be deduced/offered. Didn't you mean to take it one more template parameter?

Comment: Just make the `type_exists` stuff the default, and assume the type doesn't exist at that point. Though having specializations for every existing type doesn't make sense.

Comment: @krzaq I don't know what I want to write, I know how I want it to behave. The code is probably incorrect in many details.

Comment: I think it's the wrong approach, what's wrong with the usual preprocessor approach ( `#ifdef` and  `#endif` ) , check [boost macros](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.boost_informational_macros)

Comment: @xvan I suspect you're right about it being a problematical approach, the question is, can it be done? There's nothing wrong with macros as such, but they can introduce problems, just try to have "int errno;" in your class, you know just to pass a variable, so I'd rather try templates. I just hope it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Boost (or any other library) only if it is available, you have to use the preprocessor. C++17 comes with a handy [`__has_include`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) macro. You'd use it like the following:

```
#if __has_inlcude <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
template<typename T>
using ptr = boost::shared_ptr<T>;

#else

#include <memory>
template<typename T>
using ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;

#end
```

You could also use `#if defined(BOOST_VERSION)` to support older compilers, but this relies on specific boost headers being already included and is brittle (you risk `ptr` pointing to different things between translation units)

---

Here's some standardese (from N4140):

> §3.4.3 [basic.lookup.qual]/1:
>
> The name of a class or namespace member or enumerator can be referred
>   to after the `::` scope resolution operator applied to a
>   nested-name-specifier that denotes its class, namespace, or
>   enumeration. If a `::` scope resolution operator in a
>   nested-name-specifier is not preceded by a decltype-specifier, lookup
>   of the name preceding that :: considers only namespaces, types, and
>   templates whose specializations are types. *If the name found does not
>   designate a namespace or a class, enumeration, or dependent type, the
>   program is ill-formed.*

Comment: I don't get it. How can you check if some type exists? For testing the existence, you'll either have to know the type (which means the type exists, you need to include that declaration to check for it) or you'll have to rely on something invariable across the platforms about the type (e.g. it's name). As the first is out of question, does it happen that you know that something in the second category? I'm all ears (well... eyes actually).

Comment: if you comment out the line including boost, you'll see the problem I'm trying to solve. The rest of the code should work and switch between boost and std just based on that line, without ifdef or __has_include. I don't actually care about boost specifically, it's just an example. you can replace boost::shared_ptr with user_defined_shared_ptr (which has no specific associated macro or include file). Once that problem is solved, I think the other problems are solved too.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi you can test if a dependant type exists - and yes, you need to know its name. In my examples, if `has_type_for_some_types` did not exist - it would be a hard error. Just as it would be if `boost` wasn't declared or `boost::shared_ptr` wasn't a valid identifier to use in such context.

Comment: @Martin but if you reference a type that is not declared outside of template dependent context (as `user_defined_ptr` would be) you'll get a hard error. As far as I can tell there's no way around that. You can test if `foo<T>::type` exists safely, but only if `foo` itself won't produce a hard error due to being undefined.

Comment: @krzaq you first example: if you don't include boost::shared_ptr, then it won't compile - hard error, good bye building a solution without the header. If you include it, `boost::shared_ptr` will exist and thus your check will always be positive and the entire solution will always switch to using it. If the latter is acceptable, why not straight include it from the start as a *mandatory* prerequisite (and eventually alias `boost::shared_ptr` under another name)?

Comment: @krzaq no problem, thanks for trying. Any further ideas? I've tried abusing scope lookup rules, didn't succeed.

Comment: @krzaq Look, in languages that allow introspection, you can do it relying on the type name. E.g. in Java, `Class.forName(<name_of_the_class_as_string>)` will fail if the class is not loaded. You detect the failure and switch on whatever you like *at runtime*. But you simply can't do it at compile time... that's a non-sense to my mind.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi it is possible in C++ - but it requires preprocessor (as demonstrated in my answer).

Comment: @Martin I added a quote from the standard that I believe is relevant.

Comment: @krzaq but maybe it can be done in an indirect way, maybe construct a lookup path such that some type or function is selected based on the preferred type or the fallback type, SFINAE, I've tried but failed.Maybe abuse the argument dependent lookup, or something. What do you think?

Comment: @Martin it would still rely on, say, `boost/shared_ptr.hpp` being included. Would that satisfy you? (I'm thinking out loud here, I'm not sure it can be done)

Comment: @krzaq not really, since boost is only a placeholder for something else, an example to demonstrate it, how do you do it for chameleon::datatype ?

Comment: @Martin I'm not familiar with it. But I see no way of detecting a possible include without, well, `__has_include` (it has been added for a reason, after all). Maybe you could make `namespace::type` lookup not an error, but the include must be there.

Comment: @krzaq I'm not trying to detect an include, just the existence of a type. Think of it this way, if I have shared_ptr, it enables shared pointers, otherwise raw pointers, but I don't care if the shared_ptr comes from std, boost, dustbin or is some other thing. I just want to know if shared_ptr exists.

Comment: @Martin okay, then you must be okay with the include being there already. I can hack on that.

Comment: @Martin You are holding a fools hope: it is *not* you, but the compiler that has to know about the "concept" of shared_ptr. As you cannot use the name, the only way to describe it is by its "traits" (walks like a duck, quacks like a duck, etc) - but you still cannot tell at the compiler levek that the "signs" you are reading in the traits will actually support a `shared_ptr` functionality (i.e. it's really a duck).

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi that's actually a separate problem, there's a decent way of determining if it's a duck, sometimes it may be unreliable, sometimes it's as simple as std::is_base_of, or something like that, but it's not my question. I want to know how to determine if there's a quacking bird. This isn't about shared pointers, they were merely a familiar example, perhaps I've made the mistake of making the example too familiar. I want to know if and how I can determine if a type is defined or declared and specialize templates based on that.

Comment: @Martin It's contrary to anything I saw in C++; the usual approach: you prepare a framework of templates that will do what it needs to do with a type, then ask the programmer 'Now, here's how this works: you provide a bird that quacks and this set of templates will make it fly like a duck". You approach seems to be: "I prepare the framework and if the user doesn't provide a bird, I'll need to do something... yet to be defined".

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi it's more like here's a framework and if you provide a bird it will try to make it fly, otherwise it has a nice dog and makes it bark. And you have a good point about interfacing and types, but in my specific case it does make some kind of sense. I have a suspicion that I'll need to used macros, but the question remains, can C++ implement a constexpr something that returns true if a type is declared and specialize based on that. I've seen constexpr counters and strings, implemented them, so I wouldn't be surprised. The C++ standard is downright arcane. Magic CAN happen.

Comment: @Martin look at this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0194r0.pdf You could check if namespace exists, then if a template exists within it, but it won't ship in 17, so you're out of luck. It's a good read nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe there is no easy way to determine whether a type is defined or not when it is being compiled,  mainly due to dumbness of C++ Preprocessor.

Also, `__has_include` is not in current C++ standard AND, relying on `#if __has_include (<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>)` can't solve your problem, because you can't say that if `<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>` is included your code, then your compiler doesn't have `std::shared_ptr`.

3 Possible solutions:

1. if you wants to deal with newer standrad library with boost, consider using `<boost/config.hpp>`. For example, `BOOST_NO_CXX11_SMART_PTR` macro will help to determine whether std librry has shared_ptr or not
2. You can implement your own macros to check whether a compiler support some library or not, by checking various compiler versions. However, it wont' be easy job due to compiler options. (ex. `-std=c++03` vs `-std=c++11` of gcc)
3. Your toolchain probably can check your compiler's feature and pass it to the compiler using macro. See if [configure.ac](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/master/configure.ac) for autoconf, [FindSharedPtr.cmake](https://ceres-solver.googlesource.com/ceres-solver/+/master/cmake/FindSharedPtr.cmake) for CMake.